# how to write htaccess code for public_html file path?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get error "HTTP ERROR 500" when i migrate my website file to a new server.

my old server file path :
public_html > domain_name > .htaccess and index.php

my new server file path :
domain_name > public_html > .htaccess and index.php

.htaccess file code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Error message :

> 2020-01-16 03:02:50 UTC [apache][core:info] [pid 14130] [client
>   202.187.242.213:53382] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/u820-7jd6fjqabudn/www/lifestartoday.com/public_html/assets/admin/js/popper.min.js.map

How to modify my .htaccess file code for my new server file path?

Comment: That error message has nothing to do with your `.htaccess`.

Comment: May I know how to fix the error ?

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, you need to find the details in the logs. The message you've excerpted is just a 404 error, for a source map. It has nothing to do with the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .htaccess file code as following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

There is no need to specify the above code in mod_rewrite.
You can simply turn on the rewrite module with following commands:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Also, remove last commented line from the popper.min.js file

```
//# sourceMappingURL=popper.min.js.map
```